# What is the deference between primitive data type and wrapper classes? Is the use of primitive data type in java violation of object orientated rules?

Tags: java, oop, wrapper, primitive, primitive-types

We say that java is a "pure" object orientated language but it use primitive data type. I searched a lot I didn't get this concept that why primitive data type violation of the object orientated style.

As i read it on many websites ... and i think java is a pure oops language but I'm not able to solve this question.  please help me and share your views. 
primitive data type like:

int
float
Boolean etc.

What is the deference between primitive data type and wrapper classes?

```
Primitive data type    Wrapper class 
byte                       Byte 
short                      Short 
int                        Integer
long                       Long 
float                      Float 
double                     Double
char                       Character
```

Comment: Java isn't a "pure" OO language. Very few languages are "pure", period. There are almost always tradeoffs

Comment: Also, have you considered performance?

Comment: Because to make it "pure" OO is to make sacrifices that really aren't worth it.

Comment: please elaborate a bit more sir it will be help full for me .

Comment: Read the question Luiggi linked, and if you still don't understand, come back and ask. That question should cover the bases.

Comment: It is not pure BECAUSE it has primitive types that are not object oriented.  Therefore *knowledgable* people do not say it is a "java is a pure oops language".  (Really knowledgable wouldn't say "pure oops" about any language because "oops" is not a meaningful label for a *language*.  The correct term is object-oriented ... or OO for short.)